# How to fix firebase index issue?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

While launching the react native expo app,got this prompt.

The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/production-a9404/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Ck5wcm9qZWN0cy9wcm9kdWN0aW9uLWE5NDA0L2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy9jb2lucy9pbmRleGVzL18QARoMCghhdXRob3JJRBABGg0KCWNyZWF0ZWRBdBACGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAI

When I clicked, the google console showing error as below.

[image: firebase console]

But, this one worked earlier for a different collection and when trying for a new collection, getting this.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're signed in with an account that doesn't have permission to read or create indexes.

You should open the link from a user account that *does* have those permissions. When you do that, you'll see a screen that has all information prepopulated, and you can create the index with a single click (and some patience).

Comment: I signed out all the accounts and tried again but still same issue.i can see my previous content,which means the account is same. also but this issue exists.

Comment: Hmm... the error message is pretty explicit. If you don't click the link from the error message, but instead try to navigate to the index page yourself - can you reach it?

Comment: Yes I can reach the index page and see other indexes.but how to fix this

Comment: It got fixed once I delete all the indexes and data from the firebase and create again.As it is test environment, this is ok. What about if we get this issue in production?

Comment: I honestly have no idea why it is failing, so it's hard to say. I recommend [reaching out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting, or to [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).